# Did Janeway allow her crew to break protocol with names?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In several episodes of Voyager, senior staff are referred to by junior staff by their names, rather than their rank. For instance, in Nightingale, Harry has this exchange with Janeway:

(after Janeway tells him that he has had command experience on Voyager):

KIM: On the night shift, for a few hours. It's not the same thing. You and **Chakotay** are always a couple of decks away, ready to take over if anything goes wrong.

Since they are both on duty, shouldn't Harry refer to him as Commander?

Does this violate protocol, and if so, why was it allowed?

Comment: A lot of _Star Trek_ characters of different ranks are on a first name or nickname basis - Spock and McCoy calling Kirk "Jim", for example, or Sisko and Dax referring to each other as "Benjamin" and "Old Man". I would have to go hunting for an example but I'm sure it must've sometimes happened when they were on duty too.

Comment: "You and Commander are always" doesn't make sense. You have to use his name in order to identify who it is. The use of rank instead of name is for direct address only - "Yes Captain", not "Yes Kathryn".

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes, it should be "Commander Chakotay", not just "Commander"

Comment: I am not an expert on Voyager, but in TOS they rarely referred to anyone by rank.  Mostly it was "Mr. Sulu" or "Sulu", etc.  With the exception of the captain and, I believe, Dr. McCoy.

Comment: @Withad - Mr. Spock and Dr. McCoy were high ranking officers and close personal friends of the captain.  With that, I am pretty sure that Spock, at least, was pretty careful about when he called the Captain, "Jim".

Comment: Recently I knowted a stong endency to for hight ranking sStarfleet officers to  address eachohter by personal name in TOS.  Which of course was always there, just not noticed before.

Comment: When you've been stuck on a ship with the same people for 5 years and you're _nowhere_ near home, you do tend to get a little less formal. OTOH, they're not _nearly_ as friendly as the crew of the Equinox in the two part (S05E26/S06E01) episode _Equinox_ who have completely dispensed with rank and last names. Also, this is reflective of real life military where people are often referred to by only last name (except when there is significant difference in rank). Yeah, I know "Starfleet isn't military", except it, more or less, is.